# Installing Rudder: psql: could not connect to server

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, rudder

I'm trying to build a Docker image for Rubber, but I'm getting this error in dbconfig-common dialog.

```
unable to connect to postgresql server.
error encountered creating user:
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Also tried `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` option and had the same error:
Tried this and had the same error:

```
`Setting up rsyslog-pgsql (7.4.4-1ubuntu2.6rudder1) ...
dbconfig-common: writing config to /etc/dbconfig-common/rsyslog-pgsql.conf

Creating config file /etc/dbconfig-common/rsyslog-pgsql.conf with new version

Creating config file /etc/rsyslog.d/pgsql.conf with new version
unable to connect to postgresql server.
error encountered creating user:
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
dbconfig-common: rsyslog-pgsql configure: noninteractive fail.
dbconfig-common: rsyslog-pgsql configure: ignoring errors from here forwards`
```

I'm using Rudder 4.1 in a Ubunbu 14.04 Docker image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved this issue:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge postgresql-9.3
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3
sudo apt-get install -y rudder-server-root
```

I don't know why, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should use default value and not enter anything when rsyslog-pgsql dialog pops out.

Rudder packages will ensure that it is correctly configured during post install.

In our test procedure, We always install packages with the following commands

```
 export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive   
 apt-get -y install rudder-server-root
```

Comment: I just updated my post with the result of using noninteractive mode.